# Is 'The rest is for your imagination' right and natural?

Tags: expressions

I can only find "I will leave the rest to you" but not "The rest is for your imagination".

Let's say I'm introducing a software which provides a wide range of separate functions. Those functions can work alone, or can be combined to solve a user's problem. The user can freely combine the functions the way they want. After the initial introduction, as the conclusion, I want to say:

> The software provides multiple basic functions, the rest is up to you [the user] to combine them, let your imagination fly.

I'm trying to paraphrase the part 'Let your imagination fly' to 'The rest is for your imagination', however I'm not sure if it's right and/or natural.

Comment: None of your alternatives would be likely coming from a native speaker. *The rest is up to you* is natural English, so that's what you should use. Why are you looking for an alternative in the first place? You might be able to work in something along the lines of *...you can give your imagination free rein*, but I can't really see the point.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I want to find an alternative because 'Let your imagination fly' is used as the slogan of the software, so I try to not repeat it multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**the sky's the limit** (idiom)

> Used to say that there are no limits and that anything is possible
> "You can achieve anything if you really want to. *The sky's the limit.*" [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the%20sky%27s%20the%20limit)

> As you consider all the possibilities it seems that **the sky's the limit**! [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Knowing_You_Knowing_Them_Understanding_A/aoZeCAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22the%20sky%27s%20the%20limit%22%20possibilities&pg=PT272&printsec=frontcover).

> On the other hand, if past events are any indication of future
> possibilities—then it is fair to say that **the sky's the limit**,
> that the future of science looks bright. [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Apocryphal_Science/ZDUlj067Pp4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22the%20sky%27s%20the%20limit%22%20possibilities&pg=PR5&printsec=frontcover).

It also ties in with your slogan *Let your imagination fly.*

Comment: Yes - this one ***is*** a typical "superlative" for OP's context.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer and it's great. If you need to express the idea from this sentence "The software provides multiple basic functions, the rest is up to you, the sky's the limit" with just one single idiom (phrase), is there any suitable one? For example with the flow like this: "1. Funtion 1: bla bla; 2. Function 2: bla bla; 3. The rest...is your imagination." It will be really interesting and stylish I think :D

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a natural expression that includes "imagination" but not "fly," I suggest either:

**"I will leave the rest to your imagination"** (very common - 10m google hits - somewhat cheeky-sounding) or

**"Let your imagination run wild"** (also somewhat common but pretty close to "fly").